# Hide Worksheets Based on State Selection in a Cell

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to build a macro that after a state and number of owners are selected the macro will un-hide certain sheets that are specific to the state and number of owners. The `Sheets("List")` is a list of the states that need this specific sheet and also the number of owners. I keep running into a type mismatch error and I am stuck. Any help would be appreciated!

EDIT:

```
Sub Owners()

Sheets("Start").Activate
Dim ws As Worksheet
   For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
   If ws.Name <> ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Name Then
   ws.Visible = xlSheetHidden
   End If
   Next ws

With Worksheets("Start")
   Dim stateMatch As Variant
   stateMatch = Application.Match(.Range("B2").Value,Sheets("List").Range("K2:K32"), 0)

   Dim numOwnerMatch As Variant numOwnerMatch = Application.Match(.Range("B3").Value, Sheets("List").Range("D2:D3"), 0)

   If IsNumeric(stateMatch) And IsNumeric(numOwnerMatch) Then
   If numOwnerMatch = 1 Then
       Worksheets("1st OwnerStatement").Visible = True
       Worksheets("1st OwnerPPW").Visible = True
End If
 If numOwnerMatch = 2 Then
       Worksheets("1st OwnerStatement").Visible = True
       Worksheets("2nd OwnerStatement").Visible = True
       Worksheets("1st OwnerPPW").Visible = True
       Worksheets("2nd OwnerPPW").Visible = True
End If
End With


End Sub
```

Comment: You can't compare a single cell to multiple cells like that. You could use `Application.Match` to see if the cell's value is in the list.

Comment: Also, indenting your code properly will make it clear you are missing an `end if`. You may also want to `Sheets("Start")` instead of `ActiveSheet` -- the active sheet may not always be the one you think it is

Comment: So I have a list of 22 states where we need to only show the sheets at the bottom of the code. This was the only way I could think of typing the code with out having 22 `If` statements.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> `If ActiveSheet.Range("B2") = Sheets("List").Range("K2:K32") Then`

You can't compare a single cell to a multi-cell range like that.

Perhaps use `Application.Match` to check the single cell against the list, something like the following:

```
With Worksheets("Start")
    Dim stateMatch as Variant
    stateMatch = Application.Match(.Range("B2").Value, Sheets("List").Range("K2:K32"), 0)

    Dim numOwnerMatch as Variant
    numOwnerMatch = Application.Match(.Range("B3").Value, Sheets("List").Range("D2:D3"), 0)
End With

If IsNumeric(stateMatch) And IsNumeric(numOwnerMatch) Then
    ... unhide the sheets
End If
```

Comment: Thank you for this! This works as needed! Do you, by chance, know how I can differentiate unhidden worksheets by 1 owner or 2? Would this only be a difference in the last `If` statement?

Comment: You can then check what `numOwnerMatch` is equal to, yes, with an inner `If`.

Comment: Would I do that like below?```If IsNumeric(stateMatch) And IsNumeric(numOwnerMatch) = "1" Then
Worksheets("1st OwnerStatement").Visible = True
Worksheets("1st OwnerPPW").Visible = True
    End If
     If IsNumeric(stateMatch) And IsNumeric(numOwnerMatch) = "1" Then
Worksheets("1st OwnerPPW").Visible = True
Worksheets("2nd OwnerPPW").Visible = True
Worksheets("1st OwnerStatement").Visible = True
Worksheets("2nd OwnerStatement").Visible = True
    End If
End With```

Comment: Don't repeat the `IsNumeric` check... - `If numOwnerMatch = 1`

Comment: `If IsNumeric(stateMatch) And IsNumeric(numOwnerMatch) Then
    If numOwnerMatch = 1 Then` then unhide?

Comment: Yes if I understand what you're trying to do.

Comment: When I do this the error I get is End With without With?

Comment: Maybe edit your question with the revised code you're trying?

Comment: Edits made for you.

Comment: You're missing an `End If`.

Comment: You're still missing an `End If`. Check your [indentation](http://rubberduckvba.com/indentation).

Comment: And now I see that you got your issue resolved in a separate question. Cheers!